# Laravel 5.7: From where the password-exposed-cache comes from?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've found out this directory by accident in a project.

**The path is:**

> ```
> storage/app/password-exposed-cache
> ```

[image]

Just by looking at the directory content (sub dir named `9b`) and the file within, I can guess it's been created by a Laravel itself or a package. Not by a human.

When I open the `c34.cache` (weights `11 KB`) I just see some binary data.

[image]

What is this? Where does it come from? What does it contain? Can I delete it?

Brief internet research was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder comes with the package [laravel-password-exposed-validation-rule](https://github.com/DivineOmega/laravel-password-exposed-validation-rule) by [DivineOmega](https://github.com/DivineOmega/laravel-password-exposed-validation-rule)

Comment: Ahhh… indeed the package is installed. Good old Troy Hunt and his `haveibeenpwned`. OK. Thanks I will mark your answer as accepted as it helped me. Thank you Julian.